# What if I connected +5V from one source and GND from other to arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno

I'm just asking...
What if I connected +5V from one source and GND from other to Arduino
Will it work?

**EDIT**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO2nF2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will it work? or something?

Comment: Will it work? It won't smoke that's for sure.

Comment: Are your sources connected together somehow?

Comment: Don't make us guess what you are thinking. Be explicit and describe all details. Heck, provide a diagram if you actually want a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect the grounds of both of your sources it will work with no problem.
Otherwise if the two sources aren't connected in anyway (for example you take 5V from USB and GND from a battery) there is no way for the circuit to work, no current will flow.
If the two sources are both plugged into the mains and have earth connections (Grounding) than the 2 grounds will connect trough them. But be advised that 5V with respect to one ground may not be 5V with respect to the other ground. This can create an undervoltage or overvoltage scenario. 
Overall your question is too vague.

Comment: after the edit?

Comment: If both grounds are connected to one another, it will work fine. Otherwise it will not. The phone charger is galvanically isolated from the mains, and the circuit will not be closed.